# List of android permissions --> how they are declared to user in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

im not a developer but i need a certain piece of information that i just cant seem to find.

For an empirical analysis i need **a list that defines which a) permission "warning" in Google Play (to user) belongs to which b) actual permission.**

example: 
with an app i checked the permissions of a few apps and found combinations:

**a) Google Play says at install --> b) Actual permission used by app**

*Network communication*           --> (group.NETWORK)

full network access             --> android.permission.INTERNET

view network connections        --> android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

view Wi-Fi connections          --> android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

*Your accounts*                 --> (group.ACCOUNTS)

find accounts on the device     --> android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS

use accounts on the device      --> android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS

read Google serviceconfiguration -->google.android.providers.gsf.permissions.READ_GSERVICES

I'm looking for a full list that connects these two for each permission (if it exists) ! So i wont need to download each app during collecting data to check it with the "permission checking app"

What i already have is 
the list of all permissions with group, threat level and so on. 
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

If you know something let me know ;) thx a lot 
Luca

Answer (score 5):

> What i already have is the list of all permissions with group, threat level and so on. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

The values that you are looking for are the corresponding string resources for the `android:label` attribute.

For example, `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` is defined as:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.NETWORK"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_accessNetworkState"
    android:label="@string/permlab_accessNetworkState" />
```

The value of `@string/permlab_accessNetworkState` is defined for [English](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/strings.xml) as:

```
<string name="permlab_accessNetworkState">view network connections</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

look up here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

It's from google, so they should have everything in there

Comment: yeah i know the list, but it doesent contain exactly what i shown during installation.